# Get main class from callback in method (NODEJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, methods, callback

I need to fill profiles from database.
But can`t get property of main class. Please tell me what may be the options to solve?

**Class:**

```
class Operator {
    constructor(id) {
        this.operator_id = id;
        this.profiles = {};
    }

    getProfiles(){
        return this.profiles;
    }

    loadProfiles(){
        console.log('loading profiles');
        console.log(this.profiles);

        db.queryAll(`
        SELECT
        profiles.id,
        profiles.domain_id,
        profiles.name
        FROM
        operators_to_profiles
        LEFT JOIN profiles ON profiles.id = operators_to_profiles.profile_id
        WHERE operator_id = ${this.operator_id}
        `, function (data){
            console.log(Operator.getProfiles());
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    create : function (operator_id) {
        return new Operator(operator_id);
    }
};
```

**Usage:**

```
let operator = Operators.create(operatorId);
operator.loadProfiles();
```

**Output:**

loading profiles

{}

TypeError: Operator.getProfiles is not a function

***Solved:***

```
        WHERE operator_id = ${this.operator_id}
        `, (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(this);
        });
```

Comment: You should make your `Operator.getProfiles()` be `this.getProfiles()` (as `getProfiles() isn't static) and change the function which wraps it an arrow function

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question by adding an answer below (rather than edditing your own question)